# How to handle nullable lists using java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, option-type

I'm making a service call and trying to handle response. 
Response might have a list of something. That list might be null.

Moreover, if list not null or not empty, then
it needs to be filtered. 
In the code "entry" reference might be null if filtering gives nothing or response list is empty or null.

Currently i'm getting NPE when i try to use stream() on a null response list. 
How can i handle this situation?

```
@Getter
public class ServiceResponse {  
    List<ResponseEntry> entryList;
}

@Getter
public class ResponseEntry {
    String value;
}


ServiceResponse serviceResponse = service.getServiceResponse();
ResponseEntry entry = serviceResponse.getEntryList()
    .stream()
    .filter(e -> "expectedValue".equals(e.getValue()))
    .findFirst()
    .orElse(null);

if (entry == null) { ... }
```

Comment: Why might the list be null? The preferred return for list-valued methods with no reply is `emptyList()`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> if list not null or not empty, then it needs to be filtered.

No need for Optional here, as it's not intended to replace simple `if` checks.

```
ResponseEntry entry = null;
List<ResponseEntry> responseEntries = serviceResponse.getEntryList();
if(responseEntries != null && !responseEntries.isEmpty()){
    entry = responseEntries.stream()
                .filter(e -> "expectedValue".equals(e.getValue()))
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null);
}
```

- reads "if `responseEntries` is not null and `responseEntries` is not empty then apply the filter operation and find the first item or else null". Very readable.

On the other hand, the optional approach:

```
ResponseEntry entry = Optional.ofNullable(serviceResponse.getEntryList())
                              .orElseGet(() -> Collections.emptyList())
                              .stream()
                              .filter(e -> "expectedValue".equals(e.getValue()))
                              .findFirst();

if(!entry.isPresent()){ ... } // or entry.ifPresent(e -> ...) depending on the logic you're performing inside the block
```

- unnecessarily creates objects that could be avoided and not really the intention of optional to be used as a substitute for simple "if" checks.

Answer (score 18):

### [`Stream.ofNullable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#ofNullable(T)) (Java-9)

> Returns a sequential Stream containing a ***single element***, *if non-null*,
>   *otherwise* returns an ***empty Stream***.

#### Current Code

```
ResponseEntry entry = serviceResponse.getEntryList() // List<ResponseEntry>
        .stream() // NPE here   // Stream<ResponseEntry>
        .filter(e -> "expectedValue".equals(e.getValue())) // filter
        .findFirst() // Optional<ResponseEntry>
        .orElse(null); // or else null
```

#### Updated Code

```
ResponseEntry entry = Stream.ofNullable(serviceResponse.getEntryList()) // Stream<List<ResponseEntry>>
        .flatMap(List::stream) // Stream<ResponseEntry>
        .filter(e -> "expectedValue".equals(e.getValue())) // filter here
        .findFirst() // Optional<ResponseEntry>
        .orElse(null); // or else null
```

---

### [`Optional.stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#stream()) (Java-9)

> returns a sequential *Stream* containing ***only that value***, *otherwise*
>   returns an ***empty Stream***.

```
ResponseEntry entry = Optional.ofNullable(serviceResponse.getEntryList())
        .stream() // Stream<List<ResponseEntry>>
        .flatMap(List::stream) // Stream<ResponseEntry>
        .filter(e -> "expectedValue".equals(e.getValue())) // filter here
        .findFirst() // Optional<ResponseEntry>
        .orElse(null); // or else null
```

---

### [`Optional.isEmpty`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#isEmpty())(Java-11)

> If a value is *not present*, returns ***true***, *otherwise* ***false***

```
Optional<ResponseEntry> entry = Optional.ofNullable(serviceResponse.getEntryList()) // Optional<List<ResponseEntry>>
        .orElseGet(Collections::emptyList) // or else empty List
        .stream() // Stream<ResponseEntry>
        .filter(e -> "expectedValue".equals(e.getValue())) // filter
        .findFirst(); // Optional<ResponseEntry>

if (entry.isEmpty()) { // !entry.isPresent in java-8
   // Do your work here
}
```

Answer (score 8):

In Java 9, you could use the new method [`Objects.requireNonNullElse(T,T)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNullElse(T,T)):

```
Objects.requireNonNullElse(serviceResponse.getEntryList(),
                           Collections.emptyList())
```

Apache Commons Collections actually has a method [`ListUtils.emptyIfNull(List<T>)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-4.2/org/apache/commons/collections4/ListUtils.html#emptyIfNull-java.util.List-) which returns an empty list if the argument list is `null`. That's even better, but `Objects.requireNonNullElse` is the closest thing to it in Java SE.

If you're restricted to just Java 8, then I agree with Aomine's answer that trying to do something like go through `Optional` is worse than an `if` statement.

Answer (score 5):

You could simply use the ternary operator:

```
ServiceResponse serviceResponse = service.getServiceResponse();
List<ResponseEntry> list = serviceResponse.getEntryList();

ResponseEntry entry = (list == null ? Collections.emptyList() : list)
    .stream()
    .filter(e -> "expectedValue".equals(e.getValue()))
    .findFirst()
    .orElse(null);

if (entry == null) { ... }
```

Sometimes, traditional is better IMO.

Answer (score 3):

Another option would be to use the `Optional` [monad](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-):

```
Optional<ResponseEntry> entry = Optional.ofNullable(serviceResponse.getEntryList()).flatMap(list ->
    list.stream().filter(e -> "expectedValue".equals(e.getValue())).findFirst()
);

if (!entry.isPresent()) {
    …
}
```

You might even use [`orElseGet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseGet-java.util.function.Supplier-) instead of that `if` statement if your objective is to build (and return) a value, instead of executing a side effect.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to Optional and I may be wrong. Logic can be written like below if you want to have logic including only optional.

```
ServiceResponse serviceResponse = service.getServiceResponse();
ResponseEntry entry = 

Optional.of(CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(serviceResponse.getEntryList()))
        .filter(BooleanUtils::isTrue)
        .stream()
        .filter(e -> "expectedValue".equals(e.getValue()))
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(null);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).